# Why MySQL throws Exception when I launch my program first time: Error reading from the stream

Tags: c#, mysql

Authentication to host '127.0.0.1' for user 'root' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Reading from the stream has failed.
I've searched a lot about this issue and only Internet disconnect solved the problem. Why is that?

I use MYSQL 8 and C# winforms.

Connection code looks like this:

```
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("datasource=127.0.0.1;username=root;password=password;database=my_tests");
```

The every next try I execute the command is successful! It happens only first time.

I very appreciate your time people. And would be very thankful for constructive help for a newbie like me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I put `SslMode=None` to a string so it looks like

```
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("datasource=127.0.0.1;username=root;password=password;database=my_tests;SslMode=None");
```

the problem is gone. But I'm not sure if I want not to use it. Any other solutions would be great.

Answer (score 0):

try this code you can use the server ip address instead of local

```
string connectionString = "server=(local)\SQLExpress;database=my_tests;password:qwerty;integrated Security=SSPI;";
SqlConnection _con = new SqlConnection(connectionString)
```

Comment: I've had argument exceptions with this. But when I clean it up to look like this, the problem remains.:
                MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("server=127.0.0.1;port=3306;database=my_tests;username=root;password=password;integrated Security=SSPI;");
                conn.Open();